# bash - why does \x0d\x20 erase the line

Tags: bash, terminal, grep, cat

This is the view from gedit editor:
[image]

and the view from vim editor:
[image]

I then try to grep it, it did grep successfully if i put Log instead of Tog, but the output is corrupted:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ grep  Tog test
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ grep  Log test
                               Dtring.valueOf
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$
```

And then i cat the file, it's also corrupted:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ cat test 
                               Dtring.valueOf
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$
```

So i use hexdump:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ hexdump -C test 
00000000  4c 6f 67 2e 64 28 22 6d  75 73 69 63 22 2c 20 22  |Log.d("music", "|
00000010  4e 41 56 49 47 41 54 4f  52 3a 20 22 20 2b 20 53  |NAVIGATOR: " + S|
00000020  74 72 69 6e 67 2e 76 61  6c 75 65 4f 66 0d 20 20  |tring.valueOf.  |
00000030  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000040  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 44 0d 0a  |             D..|
00000050
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$
```

I'm narrow down it:

```
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ cat test3
                               D
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ hexdump -C test3
00000000  61 0d 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |a.              |
00000010  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |                |
00000020  20 44 0d 0a                                       | D..|
00000024
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ echo -e '\x61'
a
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ echo -e '\x61\x0d'
a
[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ echo -e '\x61\x0d\x20'

[xiaobai@xiaobai grep]$ echo -e '\x61\x0d\x20\x62'
 b
```

As you can see, the 'a' erased after i appended one \x20 byte.

So my question is, why is that happening and how can i get rid of this without prior knowledge of some files might contains \x0d\x20, e.g. grep -r ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Characters of code 0 to 31 in ASCII are control characters. When sent to a terminal, they're used to do special things. For instance, `\a` (BEL, 0x7) rings the terminal's bell. `\b` (BS, 0x8) moves the cursor backward. `\n` (LF, 0xa) moves the cursor one row down, `\t` (TAB 0x9) moves the cursor to the next tabulation...

`\r` (CR, 0xd) moves the cursor to the first column.

When you run at a shell prompt in a terminal:

```
printf 'foo\nbar\n'
```

`printf` writes `foo\nbar\n` to `/dev/tty<something>`, the tty line discipline of that device translates that to `foo\r\nbar\r\n`, which is why you see `bar` on the next line after `foo`.

```
printf 'foo\rbar\n'
```

Would have the terminal overwrite `foo` with `bar`.

If your file contains control characters, you could either remove them, or give them a textual representation (for instance `^M` or `\r` for the CR 0xd character) if you want to check for their presence.

You may not want to do that for the LF and TAB characters though. So:

```
LC_ALL=C tr -d '\0-\10\13-\37\177' < file # to remove them

cat -v < file # to display as ^M

sed -n l < file # to display as \r (also converts TAB to \t)
                # and marks the end of lines with $
```

Note that those `sed` and `cat` ones would also transform non-ASCII characters. You could do instead:

```
LC_ALL=C sed "$(printf 's/[^\t -\176\200-\377]/^&/g')" < file |
  LC_ALL=C tr '\0-\10\13-\37\177' '@-HK-_?'
```

To only convert the ASCII control characters (except TAB and LF) to their `^X` visual form (note though that not all `sed` implementations support input files with NUL characters in them).

Answer (score 4):

`\x0d` is the character `\r` which brings the cursor to the start of the line, then `\x20` is a space, so it overwrites the `a` with a space.  If you're on a unix-y system you may want to consider just removing `\r` from your output/file since it's not needed if it's for text output.  The `\n` "implies" it for *nix, but not for Windows.